# Автозапуск приложения на внешнем диске при подключении его к компьютеру

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите, можно ли сделать такое приложение и разместить его на внешнем диске, которое автоматически запускалось при подключении этого самого внешнего диска?

Сама программа будет время от времени подсчитывать место на диске и отсылать его на сервер.

Так же при отключении ЖД(Как безопасном так и выдергивании), никаких ошибок возникать не должно.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/818804 
Autorun.inf поможет. интересовался?

Comment: @ЦовакСаакян, а как на счет того, что во время выполнения программы, может быть отключен диск? Программа выдаст ошибку или можно ее тихо закрыть? Я могу понять, когда с диском ничего не происходит? Например, на диск идет копирование, после того, как оно завершается программа срабатывает и шлет инфо на сервер.

Comment: тогда твоя программа должна скопировать себя в темповую директорию, оттуда запустить себя. и дальше отдельным потоком смотришь на состояние диска, а другим потоком делаешь свои дела. 
и когда диск будет отключен, то  отправишь инфу на сервер

Comment: @ЦовакСаакян, а я могу понять, когда на диске завершилась операция копирования и он находится в простое?

Comment: думаю все можно, только знать бы как.

Comment: @iluxa1810 autorun на флейшках отключен в более-менее новых версиях win по причине активного использования вирусописателями.

Comment: @PashaPash, а правило на винде нельзя сделать, что бы авторан работал только на определенных дисках?

Comment: @iluxa1810 проще в таком случае обойтись вовсе без автозапуска - просто установить на компьютер службу, которая будет диск отслеживать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я просто как раз хотел уйти от необходимости устанавливать на каждом ПК службу(Воткнул диск и больше ничего не нужно), но видимо уйти не получится...

Comment: @iluxa1810: Мне кажется, служба — более безболезненное решение. Если вы разрешите autorun на каком-то из дисков, это будет дыра для проникновения вирусов.

Comment: @VladD, хорошо, убедили. А как узнать идет ли какая-либо работа с диском или нет(Простой)?

Comment: @iluxa1810: К сожалению, не знаю.

Comment: @iluxa1810, теоретически(!!!) можно попробовать анализировать показания системных счетчиков производительности, там штук 20 разных показателей, которые могут быть привязаны к конкретному физическому диску. Тут можно почитать как это сделать программно https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s155t6ta(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Хорошо бы пояснить сценарии, в которых предполагается использовать написанную программу. Если "я сисадмин, могу политикой расставить программу на нужные компьютеры и потом следить на сервере за цифрами" - это одно (тогда служба windows самое то, если решили не связываться с готовыми решениями по мониторингу типа SCOM, zabbix и т.п.). Если "я буду отдавать эту флешку неопытным пользователям, она должна сама при подключении запускаться, отправлять инфу на сервер, а при отцеплении корректно останавливаться" -- то нужно приложение, а не служба; умение устанавливаться от текущего непривелигиро.....

Answer (score 3):

Вы имеете в виду запуск программы с жёсткого диска при подключении диска внешнего по тому же принципу, как антивирусы запускают проверку съёмных носителей?

Тогда необходимо зарегистрировать свою программу как обработчик событий, связанных с устройствами (подробнее о них можно прочитать на MSDN в статье «[Device Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363217(v=vs.85).aspx)»). Там же, на MSDN, имеется [пример](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa363432(v=vs.85).aspx) регистрации этого обработчика. Ниже я приведу краткую выжимку из него:

1. Получаем GUID, идентифицирующий съёмные устройства (функция `HidD_GetHidGuid()`);
2. Заполняем структуру `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE` и передаём её в функцию `RegisterDeviceNotification`. Всё, обработчик зарегистрирован.
3. Обрабатываем оконное событие `WM_DEVICECHANGE`. Необходимая нам информация передаётся через `lParam`, в виде указателя на структуру `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE`, и `wParam`, в виде кода типа события. Интересующий нас код (вставка устройства) — `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL`.

Comment: А можно как-нибудь узнать находится ли диск в простое или на него что-то пишется/читается?

Comment: А к чему это необходимо знать? Вероятно, вы решаете проблему не с того конца.

Comment: Топикастер явно указал что программа должна размещаться на *самом подключаемом диске*, а не просто где-то на той машине, к которой этот диск подключается. Т.е. он спрашивал про autorun, а не просто про детект подключения устройства.

Comment: `@iluxa1810 проще в таком случае обойтись вовсе без автозапуска - просто установить на компьютер службу, которая будет диск отслеживать. – VladD` – `@VladD, хорошо, убедили...`

Comment: @iluxa1810, ещё раз: с какой целью нужно ожидать именно *простоя* диска? Вам надо подсчитать занятое место на диске — это вопрос чтения *атрибутов* файлов (несколько байт из системной таблицы), а не их содержимого. Текущая загруженность диска на это влияет слабо (тем более с учётом того, что какая-то часть атрибутов, скорее всего, уже закеширована в ОЗУ и не требует обращения к диску).

Comment: Что бы программа считала данные о кол-ве места на диске и файловую структуру, и отправила ее на сервер.

Comment: @iluxa1810 А простой-то зачем нужен? Всё равно через доли секунды дисковая активность возобновится и размер занятой области хоть немного, но всё-же изменится. Я спрашиваю о необходимости потому, что прямого способа поставить ожидание нет; а раз его нет, то стоит вернуться в Вашей проблеме немного назад и понять истинную причину необходимости ожидания неактивности диска.

Comment: @iluxa1810, как вариант, можно понизить приоритет операций ввода-вывода своего процесса: `FILE_IO_PRIORITY_HINT_INFO hint; hint.PriorityHint = IoPriorityHintVeryLow; SetFileInformationByHandle(Дескриптор_открытого_файла, FileIoPriorityHintInfo, &hint, sizeof(hint));`.

Comment: @Arhad, при простое диск может засыпать. Если ты его по таймеру пинаешь, чтобы узнать место, он будет просыпаться. Но если диск спит, то место на нём не меняется - полагаю, не надо его будить. Т. е. при первом простое запомнить место, а потом пусть спит себе, пока _кому-то ещё_ не понадобится.